# Reference for a proof of the Dehn presentation

Tags: knot-theory, gr.group-theory, reference-request

I would like a reference for a proof that the Dehn presentation is a presentation of the fundamental group of the knot complement in $\mathbb{S}^{3} $.

Comment: Double-post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264922/dehn-presentation-proof-reference-request

Comment: @dwjo8d: When you post such a question you should explain what Dehn presentation of the knot group is, what did you try to find out why it works, e.g., checked books like Crowell-Fox, Rolfsen, Burde-Zieschang, tried to google "Dehn presentation+knot group" etc. Also, avoid double posting on MO and math.stackexchange. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

L.P. Neuwirth, [Knot Groups](http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=hGunUavtc-wC&source=gbs_book_other_versions), Annals of Mathematics Studies, Princeton University Press, 1965.